# Why doesn't React.js display my local font?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change my Font import from a link to a local import.
The Chrome developer tools say Roboto is the Font Family, but it displays the standard Font.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.app {
    background-color: $white-color;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.linkRoute {
    color: $fontGrey02-color;
    text-decoration: none;
}

//remove scrollbar space to hide Scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

/* roboto-regular - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''),
         url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('.././fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure that the font files are loading correctly?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me

Comment: I just checked the Path. Every file is linked correct.

Comment: As @MaheshSamudra noted, it seems that your local font files are found at the provided path. At first glance the initial `.././` part looks unusual to me—`..` denotes the parent directory and `.` the current directory. Did you mean `../../` instead of `../.`? In any case, check your relative path for the font assets.